# How to change props of a component which I also receive as prop?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a component `Parent`

```
const Parent = () => {
 return (
  <>
   <ChildComponent icon={<Icon/>} />
  </>
)
};
```

And a component `Child`

```
const Child = ({ icon }) => {
 return (
 <>
  {icon}
 </>
)
}
```

How do can I change the props for `Icon`, inside my `Child` component? I want to dynamically change the color of the `icon`, and that's done with a color prop on the `Icon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <ChildComponent Icon={Icon} />
    </>
  )
};

const Child = ({ Icon }) => {
  const props = {}
  return (
    <>
      <Icon {...props}/>
    </>
  )
}
```